# System.Environment.NewLine and \n

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Using Visual Studio 2010 and C#

This has worked over the many years...

```
 string myString= txtSomeMultiLineTextBox.Text;
 string str = myString.Replace(System.Environment.Newline, "<br />");
```

When setting a breakpoint, if myString = LineOne\nLineTwo\nLineThree
The \n is NOT replaced... 
Then str = myString 
There is no replace.
myString remains the same

I have researched everywhere about Environment.Newline and the differences with operating environments and the one I work with is Windows 7.

This Environment will not change.

Why is Environment.Newline not reading \n ?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to ensure that line breaks are replaced no matter whether they are carriage return and line feed pairs or lone line feeds, try this:

`string str = myString.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />");`

Comment: Or use a regular expression: `Regex.Replace(input, "\r?\n", "\n");`

Comment: Generally, only use `Environment.NewLine` when writing files or to the console. When reading, use something invariant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given that you've tagged this as `asp.net` I'll assume that `txtSomeMultiLineTextBox` is ultimately a `TextArea`.

`TextArea` returns text that is delimited either by `\n` or `\r\n` depending on the specific browser version. (IE used to always use `\r\n` and now uses `\n`, strange but true.)

So probably the reason why it used to work was because you were testing on an earlier version of IE, where `\r\n` was used as the new line, whereas you're now using either IE 10, 11 or Chrome, and `\n` is the newline.

So, to be tolerant of both situations do this:

```
myString.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

And just to clear this up once and for all:

**Don't trust Environment.NewLine to solve this for you.**

If your environment is Windows, then there is no single consistent new line used everywhere, even within Microsoft products. Better to be prepared to roll up your sleeves and normalise the line endings for yourself.

Comment: You are correct. I did some testing on older browsers and it works like I expected. And thanks to others who answered..... interesting subject for us looking back ten plus years of programming!

Answer (score 5):

Because `Environment.NewLine` is platform dependent.

`Environment.NewLine` on non-Unix (... Windows) platforms is `\r\n`. That's a carriage return and line feed.

If your string contains only `\n`.. then it can't replace `\r\n`.. because that grouping isn't there.

As a test.. just replace the `\n`..:

```
string myString= txtSomeMultiLineTextBox.Text;
string str = myString.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that but I like to develop just in case there is another system/browser/etc. The question remains, WHY?

Comment: Why what? Why is it not reading `\n`? Because `Environment.NewLine` isn't `\n` on WIndows... its `\r\n` together..

Answer (score 2):

This is because System.Environment.Newline is composed of the carriage return and the new line character ie `"\r\n"` so it does not match just `"\n"